# Python Two Strings Showing as False in Comparison

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, compare

I have two characters: `⼔` and `匕`, which from now on I'll define as `char1` and `char2` from now on. In the python console, when I run `char1 == char2`, I get `False` as a result. When I run `char1 is char2`, I still get `False` as a result.

I tried to find the encoding with it, because I think it might be returning `False` because the encoding is different, but when I do `char1.encode("utf-8") == char2.encode("utf-8")` and same with the `is` command, it returns `False`.

How do I get it to recognize that these are the same characters?

Comment: They're not the same character. One is a `KANGXI RADICAL SPOON`, the other is a `CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5315`. You can see for yourself with [`unicodedata.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name).

Comment: Certain characters have very similar or identical appearances but are encoded differently. There is a Latin, Cyrillic, and Greek versions of A - all three are encoded differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⼔ and 匕 aren't the same character

- ⼔ is a radical for spoon [(see wiki)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%BC%94). Here you have [the chinese word using 匕 radical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E5%8C%95)
- 匕 is a kanji [(see wiki)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8C%95)

That's why there are different

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use Unicode::UCD qw(charinfo);
use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFKC);

my $char1 = "\N{KANGXI RADICAL SPOON}"; # ⼔
my $char2 = "\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5315}"; # 匕

print "same character considering compat decomposition\n" if
    charinfo(ord $char2)->{code}
        ==
    charinfo(ord $char1)->{decomposition} =~ s/<compat> //r;

print "normalises to the same character\n" if
    NFKC($char1) eq NFKC($char2);
```

Comment: You haven't adequately explained how your code works. Also, for "chapter 2.3" is it in the python documentary or is it about the unicode chapter 2.3 which is about compatibility. I have temporarily deleted my post to address your criticism - I will edit it soon.